# About homogeneous dimensions of a Lie group

Tags: vector-spaces, manifolds, lie-groups, lie-algebras, dimension-theory-analysis

I am looking for a clear and simplified definition of the homogeneous dimension of a vector space or a Lie group. If anyone has the patience to explain me clearly his definition and if possible an example, I would be very grateful.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you provide a link? I don't know a homogeneous dimension, but I know [homogeneous Lie groups](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-29558-9_3), or [Lie groups and homogeneous spaces](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjD2cHpn57hAhW9wcQBHaCmCq8QFjABegQIAhAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.springer.com%2Fcda%2Fcontent%2Fdocument%2Fcda_downloaddocument%2F9781461442431-c1.pdf%3FSGWID%3D0-0-45-1339003-p174506084&usg=AOvVaw3dTG-hO4BLV7-9vZQwxAuh).

Comment: @ Dietrich Burde, you can consult this book (p.37):  https://books.google.co.ma/books?id=lyuCAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA37&lpg=PA37&dq=homogeneous+dimension+of++the+heisenberg+group&source=bl&ots=Rg2UzjMBKf&sig=ACfU3U0ObQpKWCtkh_OTEfxpmUY3az2XAg&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwir04L6xZ7hAhV65eAKHWRUBMwQ6AEwB3oECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=homogeneous%20dimension%20of%20%20the%20heisenberg%20group&f=false

Comment: I don't get access to your link, please copy the definition

Comment: For a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, say nilpotent, denoting by $(\mathfrak{g}^i)_{i\ge 1}$ the lower central series, the homogeneous dimension usually denotes $\sum_ii\dim(\mathfrak{g}^i)$. For instance it equals the dimension for $\mathfrak{g}$ abelian; it equals 4 for the 3-dimensional Heisenberg Lie algebra.

Comment: If you want a geometric meaning of this notion then it captures the degree of polynomial growth of volumes of $R$-balls in the Lie group (with respect to a left-invariant Riemannian metric).